# How to join JSON data using Handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a JSON that represents a stream of comments, something like:

```
var comments = [
    { "comment_id": 1, "author_id": 100, "text": "hello world!" },
    { "comment_id": 2, "author_id": 120, "text": "cheers world!" },
    { "comment_id": 3, "author_id": 100, "text": "goodmorning world!" },
    { "comment_id": 4, "author_id": 100, "text": "goodnight world!" } ]
```

As you may notice, `author_id` 100 commented three times.

I have another JSON with my `author`s data, for example:

```
var authors = {
    100: {"username": "ciccio"},
    120: {"username": "pernacchia"} }
```

I would like to join those two JSON while rendering the template, looking up `authors` using the `author_id` as key. It would be great to have a helper like:

```
<div class="comments">
    <!-- `join` takes an iterable, a lookup dict, a key,
          and a new name for the joined property -->
    {{#join comments authors "author_id" "author"}}
    <div class="Comment">
       {{author.username}} says: {{text}}
    </div>
    {{/join}}
</div>
```

I tried to write down a helper to do this but I don't understand how to reference the `authors` dict **inside** the helper.

Right now I'm joining manually the two dicts, creating an *ad-hoc* and *new* JSON for the template.
But it would be great to delegate this work to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you will be doing this join in many places in your code, I don't think it's worth defining a helper function. Just do it with Javascript/JQuery:

```
$.each(comments, function(key, comment) {
    var author_id = comment.author_id;
    var comment_text = comment.text;
    if (authors[author_id]) {
        if (authors[author_id].text) {
            authors[author_id].text = authors[author_id].text + " " + comment.text;
        } else {
            authors[author_id].text = comment.text;
        }
    }
});
```

The above add a "text" field to "authors" record, so after this, just iterate through "authors" list.   You could also convert this into a helper function, if you really keen on that.

See it in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/DUkFa/